# calling child class method from parent class file in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, parent

`parent.py`:

```
class A(object):
    def methodA(self):
        print("in methodA")
```

`child.py`:

```
from parent import A
class B(A):
    def methodb(self):
        print("am in methodb")
```

Is there anyway to call `methodb()` in `parent.py`?

Comment: If you need to, that is a pretty significant code smell.

Comment: May be I am doing it wrong but looking for other smarter approach.

Comment: @JagadeeshNM It's hard to say what you might be doing wrong and how to be smarter, because it is not obvious what you are actually trying to achieve by doing this. Sounds a bit like your problem comes from an unhappy approach in your broader program design...

Answer (score 50):

Doing this would only make sense if `A` is an abstract base class, meaning that `A` is only meant to be used as a base for other classes, not instantiated directly. If that were the case, you would define `methodB` on class A, but leave it unimplemented:

`parent.py`:

```
class A(object):
    def methodA(self):
        print("in methodA")
        self.methodB()

    def methodB(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Must override methodB")
```

`child.py`:

```
from parent import A

class B(A):
    def methodB(self):
        print("am in methodB")
```

This isn't strictly necessary. If you don't declare `methodB` anywhere in `A`, and instantiate `B`, you'd still be able to call `methodB` from the body of `methodA`, but it's a bad practice; it's not clear where `methodA` is supposed to come from, or that child classes need to override it.

If you want to be more formal, you can use the Python [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module to declare A as an abstract base class.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):

    def methodA(self):
        print("in methodA")
        self.methodB()

    @abstractmethod
    def methodB(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Must override methodB")
```

Or if using Python 2.x:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class A(object):
 __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def methodA(self):
        print("in methodA")
        self.methodB()


    @abstractmethod
    def methodB(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Must override methodB")
```

Using this will actually prevent you from instantiating `A` or any class that inherits from `A` without overriding `methodB`. For example, if B looked like this:

```
class B(A):
   pass
```

You'd get an error trying to instantiate it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods methodB
```

The same would happen if you tried instantiating `A`.

Comment: Why set `__metaclass__` explicitly, and not just use ABC as a base class in the definition?

Comment: @naught101 When I wrote this answer, I think that using `__metaclass__` was the only way to do it (and is still the only way on Python 2.x). I agree that if you're using Python 3 these days using `ABC` as the base class is the correct way. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Suggestion: In your code, add a call to methodB inside methodA (`print("in methodA"); self.methodB()`) in the abstract/parent class. Then it's super-obvious that this answers the question.

(Context: I kept on looking for an answer, even though this is the answer, overlooking another problem with my code that made it seem as if this wouldn't work.)

Comment: @dasWesen Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 22):

You can do something like this:

```
class A():
    def foo(self):
        self.testb()

class B(A):
    def testb(self):
        print('lol, it works')
b = B()
b.foo()
```

Which would return this of course:

```
lol, it works
```

Note, that in fact there is no call from parent, there is just call of function `foo` from instance of child class, this instance has inherited `foo` from parent, i.e. this is impossible:

```
a=A()
a.foo()
```

will produce:
    `AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'testb'`

because

```
>>> dir(A)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'foo']
>>> dir(B)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'foo', 'testb']
```

What I've wanted to show that you can create instance of child class, and it will have all methods and parameters from both parent and it's own classes.

Answer (score 2):

There are three approaches/ways to do this ! but I highly recommend to use the approach #3 because composition/decoupling has certain benefits in terms of design pattern. ([GOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance))

```
## approach 1 inheritance 
class A():
    def methodA(self):
        print("in methodA")
    def call_mehtodB(self):
        self.methodb()

class B(A):
    def methodb(self):
        print("am in methodb")

b=B()
b.call_mehtodB()


## approach 2 using abstract method still class highly coupled
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class A(ABC):
    def methodA(self):
        print("in methodA")
    @abstractmethod    
    def methodb(self):
       pass

class B(A):

    def methodb(self):
        print("am in methodb")

b=B()
b.methodb()

#approach 3 the recommended way ! Composition 

class A():
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message=message

    def methodA(self):
        print(self.message)

class B():
    def __init__(self,messageB, messageA):
        self.message=messageB
        self.a=A(messageA)

    def methodb(self):
        print(self.message)

    def methodA(self):
        print(self.a.message)

b=B("am in methodb", "am in methodA")
b.methodb()
b.methodA()
```

Comment: In your 3rd suggestion, how do you d `a=A()` and `a.methodb()` (which is what the original question is, if i'm not wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function anywhere *so long as it was attached to an object*, which it appears to be from your sample. If you have a `B` object, then you can use its `methodb()` function from absolutely anywhere.

`parent.py:`

```
class A(object):
    def methoda(self):
        print("in methoda")

def aFoo(obj):
  obj.methodb()
```

`child.py`

```
from parent import A
class B(A):
    def methodb(self):
        print("am in methodb")
```

You can see how this works after you import:

```
>>> from parent import aFoo
>>> from child import B
>>> obj = B()
>>> aFoo(obj)
am in methodb
```

Granted, you will not be able to create a new `B` object from inside `parent.py`, but you will still be able to use its methods if it's passed in to a function in `parent.py` somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If the both class in same .py file then you can directly call child class method from parents class.
It gave me warning but it run well.

class A(object):

```
def methodA(self):

    print("in methodA")

    Self.methodb()
```

class B(A):

```
def methodb(self):

    print("am in methodb")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this -

`parent.py`

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,obj):
        self.obj_B = obj

    def test(self):        
        self.obj_B.methodb()
```

`child.py`

```py
from parent import A

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        super().__init__(self)
   
    def methodb(self):
        print("in method b with id:",self.id)
```

Now if you want to call it from class B object

```py
b1 = B(1)
b1.test()

>>> in method b with id: 1
```

Or if you want to call it from class A object

```py
b2 = B(2)
a = A(b2)
a.test()

>>> in method b with id: 2
```

You can even make new objects in super class by invoking class dict objects of the object passed to super class from child class.